# GA data layer only showing last product

Tags: google-analytics

I set up a GA data layer to show up on my cart complete page.
The code looks like:

```
{
 'transactionId': 84,   'transactionTotal': 15, 'transactionAffiliation': 'Online',  'transactionProducts': [
{'name': 'card1', 'category': 'Giftcard', 'price': 5, 'quantity': 1,'sku1': 'card'},
{'name': 'card 2', 'category': 'Giftcard', 'price': 10, 'quantity': 1,'sku2': 'card'}
]}
```

It comes through but when we click for full details on the transaction it only shows up as quantity : 1 and the information on the last product listed:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi**

Hey, i've tested your code and it pushed both element into the array, and this is the expected behavior on the dataLayer.

[image]

**BUT!**, here is an issue with the SKU field, use the correct sintaxis, replace the sku1 and sku2 for the correct key : "sku". Also the Js library has a limitation ( actually the tool), you can only add unique SKU on each transaction, **so you have to take one option:**

If the product is the same, you need to sum the price and put quantity as 2:

*In this case you sell 2 product of 7.5 each*

```js
dataLayer.push({
 'transactionId': 84,   'transactionTotal': 15, 'transactionAffiliation': 'Online',  'transactionProducts': [
{'name': 'card 2', 'category': 'Giftcard', 'price': 15, 'quantity': 2,'sku': 'card'}
]})
```

or the other option is make unique the sku field
*you will desagregate the product make it harder to find it via SKU*

```js
dataLayer.push({
 'transactionId': 84,   'transactionTotal': 15, 'transactionAffiliation': 'Online',  'transactionProducts': [
{'name': 'card1', 'category': 'Giftcard', 'price': 5, 'quantity': 1,'sku': 'card1'},
{'name': 'card 2', 'category': 'Giftcard', 'price': 10, 'quantity': 1,'sku': 'card2'}
]})
```